# Improving a Tikz Diagram

Tags: latex, tikz, pgf

I have just finished my first diagram in Tikz. It looks as I wanted it to, but am unhappy with how I have 'coded' it:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[node distance=14mm,
 item/.style={rounded corners,rectangle,
   thick,
   minimum width=20mm, minimum height=10mm}]

\node[item,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20] (stack) {1394 Stack};
\node[item,left=of stack,draw=green!50,fill=green!20,yshift=-9mm] (app1) {Application};
\node[item,left=of stack,draw=green!50,fill=green!20,yshift=9mm] (app2) {Application};
\node[item,right=of stack,draw=orange!50,fill=orange!20] (ohci) {OHCI};
\node[item,right=of ohci,yshift=-15mm,draw=yellow!70,fill=yellow!35] (dev1) {Device};
\node[item,right=of ohci,yshift=0mm,draw=yellow!70,fill=yellow!35] (dev2) {Device};
\node[item,right=of ohci,yshift=15mm,draw=yellow!70,fill=yellow!35] (dev3) {Device};

\draw[thick] (app1) -- (stack)
             (app2) -- (stack)
             (stack) -- (ohci)
             (ohci) -- (dev1)
             (ohci) -- (dev2)
             (ohci) -- (dev3);

\node[xshift=7mm,yshift=1mm] (topUser) at (app1.east |- dev3.north) {};
\node[xshift=7mm,yshift=-1mm,label=above left:User space] (botUser) at (app1.east |- dev1.south) {};
\draw[dashed] (topUser) -- (botUser);

\node[xshift=7mm,yshift=1mm] (topKern) at (stack.east |- dev3.north) {};
\node[xshift=7mm,yshift=-1mm,label=above left:Kernel space,
label=above right:Hardware\phantom{p}] (botKern) at (stack.east |- dev1.south) {};
\draw[dashed] (topKern) -- (botKern);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The things which I am uncomfortable with are:

How I have manually moved the "Application" and "Device" nodes using `yshift` to space them apart from one another; I am sure that there must be a more elegant way of producing a simple tree-like structure

The lines (`topKern -- botKern` and `topUser -- botUser`) going from the top of the picture to the bottom; these are manually aligned on the x-axis to be between two nodes using `xshift=7mm`.

My use of `\phantom{p}` to ensure the label "Hardware" has the same baseline as the other two labels.

Comment: FYI, this kind of question would find a very good home on the [TeX/LaTeX Stack Exchange site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), now in public beta. If you like, you can close this question and repost it on the other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a tree structure, consult `pgfmanual.pdf`, *Making Trees Grow*.

For the lines, I would create nodes representing in the middle of two nodes, and then use the perpendicular coordinate system as you did. Also you can use `current bounding box` to identify the "border".

To align baselines correctly, specify `text height` and `text depth`. In your case, for instance in the style `every label`. But as you see, I did the labels as nodes below...

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=35mm,node distance=15mm,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.25ex]

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={rounded corners,rectangle,thick,minimum width=20mm, minimum height=10mm}]
\begin{scope}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=19mm,nodes={fill=green!20,draw=green!50}}]
\node[draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20] (stack) {1394 Stack} [grow=left]
  child {node (app2) {Application}}
  child {node (app1) {Application}};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=15mm,nodes={fill=yellow!70,draw=yellow!35}}]
\node[right= of stack,draw=orange!50,fill=orange!20] (ohci) {OHCI} [grow=right]
  child {node {Device}}
  child {node {Device}}
  child {node {Device}};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}

\node[below=0mm of app1] (userspace) {User space};
\node at (userspace -| stack) (kernel) {Kernel};
\node at (userspace -| ohci) (hardware) {Hardware}; 

\path (app1) -- (stack) node[coordinate,midway] (between1) {};
\draw (ohci) -- (stack) node[coordinate,midway] (between2) {};

\draw[dashed] (current bounding box.north -| between1) -- (current bounding box.south -| between1);
\draw[dashed] (current bounding box.north -| between2) -- (current bounding box.south -| between2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: What is the difference between the \path and \draw commands (app1 -- stack) and (ohci) -- (stack); I can see that changing the \path to a \draw results in a 'double line'. Is it just to get the coordinates for use later?

Comment: @Freddie: The `\path` command just constructs a path. The `\draw` command also constructs a path, but in addition draws the path. The `\path` command is just to get the coordinate, and the `\draw` command does two things at once. This is a hack. I really wanted to put everything in one tree, but it wasn't possible. It should be, but if I try to grow two nodes to the left and one to the right, the left nodes will be laid out as if there would be three nodes to the left.